# How to generate a Safari suggested type password using Keychain Access app?

Tags: icloud, applications, safari, password, keychain

Web forms usually allow Safari to suggest and create a password that has a specific format. Can you generate one – not necessarily graphically (via Automator or Script Editor) – of the same format with Keychain Access too?

[image: password format]
Password format

[image]
Password suggestion

Comment: *Usually, web forms allow the browser to suggest a password in a specific format...*  What web forms are you using that allows your ***browser*** to suggest a password format???  With that said, what exactly is the question here?  This reads like a feature request.

Comment: @Allan forms in context of web and passwords are usually of log-in or sign-up nature. Of course, I could reiterate the question for you individually, but I'd repeating the sentences from title and description that end with a question mark. As far as feature requesting goes, with that logic everyone who does not know how to accomplish a certain thing and tries to describe it is making one. Anyway, thank you for your effort.

Comment: I didn't ask what the web forms were asking, I asked you to clarify which *browsers*, since you referenced it, allow you to do this. This response doesn't clarify whether this is a bona fide question or a feature request.

Comment: @Allan are you trying to help? I wrote "the browser". The question itself is "safari" tagged. I even mentioned it further down the line.

Comment: 1) It's a rhetorical question.  Safari doesn't do this.  2) This sounds like a feature request.  All of this is to **help** you ask a question that gets answered.  It's probably best that you review  [How To Ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in our [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/)

Comment: @Allan no, it wasn't. I'd know. And you clearly have a problem reading even your own questions. I'm sorry.

Comment: Can you please add a specific example (screenshots for instance) to explain what you are looking for?

Comment: @patrix feedback taken.

Comment: @Allan What part of "How to generate a Safari suggested type password using Keychain Access app?" didn't you understand?